# cant edit webpart on page layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, page-layout

on my dev environnement i develop a new page layout with different webpart zone and it works fine.

When I deployed on my test environnement , i can't see and even edit/delete/add "a Web Part",

The only difference here is , the dev is on english and the test is on frensh langage.

the role of user is contribute.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the same language pack installed on the DEV server? Can you verify the "Language" tag on your page layout and try to update. Here are articles explains the language specific page layouts and required codes.

https://www.eliostruyf.com/multilingual-user-interface-in-page-layouts-and-master-pages/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splocale.lcid.aspx

Comment: Thank you , the probleme was with the navigator IE, we need to activate the js , with chroem it works fine